# What better send 1 large file or af few small?

Tags: file, copy, system

I need to copy large files (100Gb) by TCP/IP. I know that system will split files on chunks, but may be also better split these files on small - near 5 - 10 GB? I am afraid about system resources. A

Comment: keep in mind the file system limitations for the receiving end (ntfs, fat etc) splitting may not be such a bad idea, especially if you do not want to load the entire file in memory on the sending side.

Comment: yes, splitting the file makes sense. Espec if your link is over wan (not 100% uptime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, your network is sure to be the bottle-neck in your copy process. You will be using additional system resources to split the file as well.

Comment: I wouldn't want to load the entire file in memory before sending